# SQL Server Case Statement Query

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure which has some parameters and want to write a case statement
in query giving me syntax error. Can you help me how to write case statement?

```
Select *
FROM table1 ssr
left join table2 sse on ssr.case_nbr=sse.case_nbr
left join table3 m on m.MemberId=sse.memberid
where 
    (
        @searchValue IS NULL Or
        concat(last_name, first_name) like '%' + @searchValue + '%' 
        or mrn like '%' + @searchValue + '%' or FIN like '%' + @searchValue + '%' 
    )
AND (@searchFirst IS NULL Or first_name like '%' + @searchFirst + '%')

//i want to write a case statement 
AND (@statusfilter IS NULL OR 
                    CASE 
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('NEW', @statusfilter) = 0
                    THEN
                        (sse.Status in (select splitdata from dbo.fnSplitString(@statusfilter,'|')))
                    ELSE
                        (sse.Status is Null OR sse.Status in (select splitdata from dbo.fnSplitString(@statusfilter,'|')))
                        
                    END
    )
```

Comment: CASE is not a control-of-flow statement in TSQL - you need to understand that and adjust how you use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return value from the `CASE`, You can use `IIF` inside `THEN` and return `1` or `0` and compare that value.

```
    AND (
        @statusfilter IS NULL 
        OR 
            1 = CASE 
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('NEW', @statusfilter) = 0 
                        THEN IIF(sse.Status in (select splitdata from dbo.fnSplitString(@statusfilter,'|')), 1, 0) 
                    ELSE IIF((sse.Status is Null OR sse.Status in select splitdata from dbo.fnSplitString(@statusfilter,'|')), 1, 0)
                END
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use normal boolean logic, which after cleaning up becomes this:

```sql
AND (
      @statusfilter IS NULL OR 
      (
        (
          (CHARINDEX('NEW', @statusfilter) > 0 AND sse.Status IS NULL)
        )
        OR sse.Status in (select splitdata from dbo.fnSplitString(@statusfilter, '|'))
      )
    )
```

Note that I *strongly* recommend you use a Table Valued Parameter instead of a split string.

At the very least, you should use the built-in string splitting function `STRING_SPLIT` (and I hope you are not on an unsupported version which doesn;t have it).